# docopt positional arguments not working

Tags: python, docopt

When followint the docopt README, I would expect the following file to produce some valid output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Example file.

Usage:

  test_docopt.py test
  test_docopt.py (-h | --help)
  test_docopt.py --version

Options:
  -h --help                       Show this screen
  --version                       Show version.

"""

import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("docopt==0.6.1")
from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt(__doc__, version="Extend limb profiles 0.1")
    print(args)
```

However, when I call `test_docopt.py`, I only get a meaningless/empty *Usage* statement:

```
$ python test_docopt.py test
Usage:
```

My two questions are:

- Why is docopt apparently failing to recognize the *test* command?
- Why isn't the *Usage* pattern filled with the actual usage pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the empty line between `Usage:` and the usage itself. From [README.rst](https://github.com/docopt/docopt#usage-pattern-format)

> Usage pattern is a substring of doc that starts with usage: (case insensitive) and ends with a visibly empty line.

By putting an empty line right after `Usage:` you end the usage pattern right there.